# show that $γ$ also passes through the point $(\sqrt 2,0)$.

Tags: geometry, curves

> Let $\gamma$ be the curve which passes through $(0,1)$ and intersects each curve of the family
>   $y=cx^2$ orthogonally. Then show that $γ$  also passes through the point $(\sqrt 2,0)$.

I  am unable to understand is the question demanding to find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y=x^2$ because here the curve meets each curve of the family orthogonally.

I am unable to understand what to do in the given problem.Please give some hints

Comment: "**the** curve"? Hmmm ... The $y$-axis itself is **a** curve that satisfies the given hypotheses, as is any curve through $(0,1)$ that happens to have a vertical tangent at the origin. Perhaps these are disqualified by the context in which the problem appears, but the problem as stated here is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\gamma$ passes through the point $(x,y)=(x,cx^2)$. At that point, the derivative of $\gamma$ has to be orthogonal to the derivative of $y=cx^2$, the latter of which is $2cx$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac1{2cx}=-\frac x{2cx^2}=\frac{-x}{2y}$$
We've got a separable differential equation. Solving:
$$2y\ dy=-x\ dx$$
$$\int2y\ dy=\int-x\ dx$$
$$y^2=-\frac12x^2+K$$
Since $\gamma$ passes through $(0,1)$:
$$1^2=-\frac120^2+K\implies K=1$$
Hence the equation of $\gamma$ is
$$y^2=-\frac12x^2+1$$
Since $(x,y)=(\sqrt2,0)$ satisfies this equation, $\gamma$ passes through $(\sqrt2,0)$ as well.